# Mobile Safari and dynamically loading images affects performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, mobile-safari

I am developing a web site that is specifically targeted for Mobile Safari. Imagine a camera (the window) which travels around a world (the document) on a random and automatic basis. Within this world we have a series of images. When the camera moves to a part of the world where images are not present, new images are asynchronously loaded in from Flickr.

Have I lost you yet? Bear with me... When said Flickr images are being loaded in, the smooth motion of the camera is affected drastically. I understand that mobile devices have less memory and processing power, but could there be a solution which will load images in dynamically without affecting the camera's movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so. Each image loaded into the DOM requires memory and processing in order to be rendered. The more image you have loaded in the DOM the more memory the page takes up. Each image that gets rendered and inserted into the DOM requires processing power.